# Calling a Javascript function from a html file

Tags: javascript

My javascript and html files named contents.js and page.html:

```js
function sayHello() {
   alert("Hello World")
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>     
   </head>
   
   <body>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="contents.js" ></script>
   <script>
      window.onload = sayHello();
   </script>
      
   </body>
</html>
```

When run the sayHello function isn't being called. In firefox's console it returns the errors:

-SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'  contents.js:1

ReferenceError: sayHello is not defined

Both files are saved in the same folder. And i'm using a node.js express project in eclipse to create the server:

```js
var http = require('http'),
    fs = require('fs');


fs.readFile('./page.html', function (err, html) {
    if (err) {
        throw err; 
    }       
    http.createServer(function(request, response) {  
        response.writeHeader(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});  
        response.write(html);  
        response.end();  
    }).listen(8888);
});
```

Why am I not able to call the 'sayHello' function in the contents.js file from the page.html file?

Comment: `window.onload = sayHello();` assigns the return value from `sayHello` to `window.onload`. What do you return?

Comment: You forgot to use a trigger event. Like `onload` or `onpageshow`.

Answer (score 2):

The code

```
window.onload = sayHello();
```

...**calls** `sayHello` and assigns its return value to `window.onload`, exactly the way `x = foo()` **calls** `foo` and assigns its return value to `x`.

To just assign the function reference, don't call it (remove the `()`):

```
window.onload = sayHello;
```

---

Side note: The window `load` event happens very late in the page load cycle, only after all other resources are loaded, including all images. Most of the time, you want to run your code earlier. If so, just put it in a `script` tag that you include at the *end* of the HTML, just before the closing `</body>` tag.

Comment: To expand, `sayHello()` returns `undefined` so `window.onload` is being set to `undefined` which is why nothing happens.

Answer (score 1):

Executing sayHello() , you arenot returning anystuff so it was not executed. Had `sayHello` been returning a function it would have invoked that onload.

```
var sayHello = (function() {
  return function {
    alert("Hello World")
  };
})();
```

In this situation, one might use sayHello(), as its returning a function.

```js
window.onload = sayHello;

function sayHello() {
  alert("Hello World")
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="contents.js"></script>

</body>


</html>
```

Comment: Please add an explanation. Just code doesn't help anyone.

Comment: Hey @AndrewL. Thanks for pointing it out, I just about to update it. I hope you would reconsider your opinion. Will be catious next time bro!

Comment: I tried this and the reference error is now gone but im still getting: SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<' contents.js:1 and the alert is not appearing.

Comment: Hey @user2562530 Can you just run the snippet I shared, it has the alert(). just run it once.

Comment: Okay it works here but when I copy it to eclipse i still get the syntax error. What can I do?

Comment: Yea that means there is something fishy in content.js. See your error was `'<' contents.js:1`, which means in lineNo.1 of your content.js. Some js error is happening. As a JS error is thrown, rest code dont execute. can you create a fiddle and place the content of content.js, so that I can help.

Comment: No instead using this line `<script type="text/javascript" src="contents.js"></script>`, replace it with the content inside content.js. So that we can view the file.

Comment: I don't understand. How do you want me to show you the file?

Answer (score -1):

Put it inside the body tag like this.

```
<body onload="sayHello()"></body>
```